# Cannot load persisted db using Chroma / Langchain

Tags: langchain, chromadb, gpt4all, privategpt

I ingested all docs and created a collection / embeddings using Chroma. I have a local directory db. Within db there is chroma-collections.parquet and chroma-embeddings.parquet. These are not empty. Chroma-collections.parquet when opened returns a collection name, uuid, and null metadata.

When I load it up later using langchain, nothing is here.

```
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=embeddings_model_name)
CHROMA_SETTINGS = Settings(
        chroma_db_impl='duckdb+parquet',
        persist_directory='db',
        anonymized_telemetry=False
)

db = Chroma(persist_directory='db', embedding_function=embeddings, client_settings=CHROMA_SETTINGS)
```

`db.get()` returns `{'ids': [], 'embeddings': None, 'documents': [], 'metadatas': []}`

I've tried lots of other alternate approaches online. E.g.

```
import chromadb

client = chromadb.Client(Settings(chroma_db_impl="duckdb+parquet",
                                    persist_directory='./db'))
coll = client.get_or_create_collection("langchain", embedding_function=embeddings)
coll.count() returns 0
```

I'm expecting all the docs and embeddings to be available. What am I missing?

Comment: directly remove the chroma_db_impl in chroma_settings. But I still meeting the problem that the database files didn't created after db.persist().

Comment: another alternative is to downgrade the langchain to 0.0.322, chromadb==0.3.29, keep install duckdb==0.71

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the langchain dokumentation was wrong https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/19807

You can change

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
```

to

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores.chroma import Chroma
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem too and found it is beacause my program ran chromadb in **jupyter lab** (or **jupyter notebook** which is the same).

In [chromadb official git repo example](https://github.com/hwchase17/chroma-langchain/blob/master/persistent-qa.ipynb), it says:

> In a notebook, we should call persist() to ensure the embeddings are written to disk. This isn't necessary in a script - the database will be automatically persisted when the client object is destroyed.

So, If your program is also ran in **jupyter env**，the best way is to call client.persist() everytime when you need to save your modification to chromadb's local persistence. The example code is as follow:

```py
import chromadb

client = chromadb.Client(Settings(chroma_db_impl="duckdb+parquet",
                                    persist_directory='./db'))
coll = client.get_or_create_collection("langchain", embedding_function=embeddings)

... # any modifications on chromadb, include create, upsert, delete...

client.persist() # save modifications above to chroma's local persistence
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to add collection_name while saving/loading Chromadb.

#### save to disk

```
db2 = Chroma.from_documents(docs, embedding_function,  persist_directory="./chroma_db", collection_name='v_db')
db2.persist()
docs = db2.similarity_search(query)
```

#### load from disk

```
db3 = Chroma(collection_name='v_db', persist_directory="./chroma_db", embedding_function)
docs = db3.similarity_search(query)
print(docs[0].page_content)
```